# Run my android program on real smartphone Android 4

Tags: android, ubuntu, adt

I'm writing Android application on Ubuntu ADT and run it on device with Android version 2.3. How can I run on android version 4.X?

Comment: Download it to the actual device?  Either that, or download the definition for the ADT emulator that is 4.x.

Comment: So it's the problem that I can't Download App to actual devise with OS version 4.X

Comment: @user3560634 : How are you trying to download it to the device?

Comment: What I usually do is take the compiled APK file, upload it to my website, download it to the device and install it there...

Comment: Just Run via USB. Yes of course I can download from website, but it's not option, because I have to test frequently

Comment: @user3560634 : What device is it? Do you have USB drivers installed for it?

Comment: Look here http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-eclipse.html
But it doesn't work. I cant write udev rules correctly

Comment: @user3560634 : Have you enabled Developer Options? If so, show what you've done to try to write the udev rules.

Comment: SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev" 
Device is HTC Desire

Comment: @user3560634 : Did they release a version of the Desire with Android 4.x? Or is it a custom ROM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I run on android version 4.X?

The same way you run it on any Android device -- by enabling USB debugging in Developer Options and plugging in the device. You might need to [tweak some `udev` values on your Ubuntu box](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html), but that's not likely.

Comment: The problem is That I can't write udev rules correctly =(

Comment: @user3560634: Without knowing your device make and model, nobody can help you with that.

Comment: Device is HTC Desire
I've write 
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev" 

in 51-androi.rules as in instruction

Comment: @user3560634: Drop the `GROUP="plugdev"` piece. Then restart `udev`. Then unplug/re-plug in the device. And, again, you need to have the USB debugging option enabled. Note that it may pop up a dialog on the device to allow you confirm that you want to debug from this Ubuntu machine, depending on what version of Android the Desire runs. But I have `SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666"` in my `51-android.rules` file, and it works fine.